# How to return a value based on fixture value in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to return a value based on fixture value and when I call the method from another class i am getting result as undefined.

```
Class A:
    getTestEnv() {
            let test;
            cy.fixture("Properties/env.json").then((profile) => {
              var df = profile.test_env;
              if (df.match(/d\d+/)) {
                test = `random.${df}.test.com`;
              } else {
                test = `random.${df}.autotest.com`;
              }
              return test;
            });
          }


Class B:
getDetails() {
  let env = this.getTestEnv();
  cy.log("env: " + env);   // Undefined
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have missed some return values.

The first method returns the fixture, then the second method will call that first method in the same way it would call the `cy.fixture()` itself, that is it will use a `.then()` to obtain the fixture value from the returned value

```js
Class A:
   getTestEnv() {
            let test;
      return cy.fixture("Properties/env.json").then((profile) => {
              var df = profile.test_env;
              if (df.match(/d\d+/)) {
                test = `random.${df}.test.com`;
              } else {
                test = `random.${df}.autotest.com`;
              }
              return test;
            });
          }

getDetails() {
  this.getTestEnv().then(env => {
    cy.log("env: " + env);   
  }
```